# Get URL or HTML of clicked link within Android EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannable

I'm trying to **retrieve the URL** of the clicked link in an **EditText**. I want to touch a link, and then do something with its URL. The closest I've gotten is to determine if the span where the cursor sits is a URLSpan style:

```
int s1 = Math.max(mText.getSelectionStart(), 0);
int s2 = Math.max(mText.getSelectionEnd(), 0);
Spannable raw = new SpannableString(mText.getText());
CharacterStyle[] spans = raw.getSpans(s1, s2, CharacterStyle.class);
for (CharacterStyle span : spans) {
    if(span.getClass().equals(android.text.style.URLSpan.class)){
        //is a link, but what is the URL?

    }
}
```

If I convert it all to an HTML string then I don't know how to relate the cursor position of plain text to the html text. I can get all the URLs in an EditText with `getUrls()`, but still do not know which one was clicked. If I could do something like: `EditText.getPortion(start, end).getUrls()`, that would be closer, but I've seen no methods for anything like that so far.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a 4 year old response, but to answer for future visitors:

```
for (CharacterStyle span : spans) {
    if(span.getClass().equals(android.text.style.URLSpan.class)){
        //you almost had it here, just cast the span as a URLspan
        URLSpan u = (URLSpan)spans[j];
        String span_url = u.getURL();
    }
}
```